# Custom DatePickerDialog with Week number

Tags: android, datepicker, android-custom-view, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I want to show either a `datePickerDIalog` or `CalendarView` with week number on the view. Calendar View had this feature before but now its deprecated. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I couldn't find any external libraries too.